# Variable not being inserted into url string

Tags: javascript, html

The problem i am facing is the variable that is to be pulled from the onsubmit function is not properly being reinserted into the url. It leaves me with the core url string minus where the variable would go and everything after the variable

```
<html>
<BODY bgcolor="black"> 
<FONT size="2"><FONT color="red"><B>RET 5 MAN</B></FONT>
<TABLE>
<TBODY><TR><TD>
<FORM method="post" target="_parent" style="margin: 0;" action="http://impulse-ow.com/bar.html">
<INPUT name="sublogin" type="submit" style="width:150px" formtarget="_self"  value="HOME">
</FORM>
</TD>
</TD>  

<br>   


<TABLE>
<TBODY><TR><TD>
<FORM method="post" target="_new" style="margin: 0;" action="http://zimbob.outwar.com/world.php?suid=141535">
<INPUT name="sublogin" type="submit" style="width:75px"  value="FORM!">
</FORM>
</TD>
<TD> 
<FORM method="post" target="_new" style="margin: 0;" action="http://zimbob.outwar.com/joinraid.php?raidid=" + document.getElementsByID('linkfive').value; + "&" + uid=141535 + "&" + serverid=4 + "&" + "launchraid=yes">      
<INPUT name="launch" type="submit" style="width:75px"  value="LAUNCH!">
</FORM>
</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY></TABLE>
<br>


<form onsubmit="linkfive()" id="linkfive" method="post" >
<font color="red">Raid Link:</font><br> <input type="text" />
<input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
</form>




<TD><table>
<FORM method="post" target="_new" style="margin: 0;" action="http://impulse-ow.com/5mansin.html">
<INPUT name="sublogin" type="submit" style="width:75px"  value="SiN">
</FORM>
<FORM method="post" target="_new" style="margin: 0;" action="http://impulse-ow.com/5mantomes.html">
<INPUT name="sublogin" type="submit" style="width:75px"  value="Tomes">
</table>
 </form>   
</TD>

</TR>
<br>

<TABLE>
<TBODY><TR><TD>
<FORM method="post" target="_new" style="margin: 0;" action="http://zimbob.outwar.com/joinraid.php?raidid=" + document.getElementsByID('linkfive').value + "&" + suid36642>
<INPUT type="submit" style="width:150px" value="Account name" >
</FORM>
</TD>
</TR>

</TBODY></TABLE>

<script type="text/javascript">

function linkfive() {
     var linkfive = document.getElementById('linkfive').value
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Like i said before very basic coding. This might be somewhat sloppy or the fix might be something stupid i missed, but i have been at this for a good 5 days now with no progress.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem originates far earlier: your design is quite messed up but don't worry it's quite normal for a beginner. To help others to provide you the best answer, please, explain better what is the general problem you're trying to solve, especially why you need to manipulate the url in such a messy way

Comment: Also, i think you're going to need some server scripting language, like PHP, to resolve this. (or maybe not, are the 2 forms in the same page?)

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the whole thing as a string.
try this:

```
<FORM method="post" target="_new" style="margin: 0;" action="http://genericurl.com/restofurl?url=" + document.getElementsByID('urlid').value + "&" + remainingurl>
    <INPUT name="sublogin" type="submit" style="width:150px"  value="Submit1">
```

This way you will not use the words literally but the values in them.

You are not getting the value from the input field. 
Put an ID on the input so you can grab it:

```
<form onsubmit="linkfive()"  method="post" >
<font color="red">Raid Link:</font><br> <input id="linkfive" type="text" />
<input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
</form>
```

this way `document.getElementsByID('urlid').value` will have the input field value.

Comment: @xSpaZx this is because you never get the value. Try the updated version

Comment: I'm still having issues with this code. Do you mind if I post the entire script and you take a peak at it and see where I messed up?

Comment: @xSpaZx Sure, Update you question and put whatever error messages you get too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<FORM method="post" target="_new" style="margin: 0;" action="http://genericurl.com/restofurl?url=" + urlid.value + "&" + remainingurl>
<INPUT name="sublogin" type="submit" style="width:150px"  value="Submit1">
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the semicolon ; from urlid.value;
seperate the literal "&" from your remainingurl variable

"http://genericurl.com/restofurl?url=" + urlid.value + "&" + remainingurl